# Feasible attacks on ECRSA cryptosystem

Tags: rsa, public-key, elliptic-curves

In **ECRSA** cryptosystem, I want to know the feasible attacks. For illustrations we have two prime $p$ and $q$ such that $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, $q \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and generate key pair as follows:
$$n = pq, \quad \lambda = \operatorname{lcm}(p+1,q+1), \quad d = e^{-1} \pmod \lambda $$
Now $(n, e)$ is public and $(n, d)$ is private key.

For given message $m$, we present $m$ as a pair of integers $(m_1, m_2) \pmod n$ and regards it as a point $P$ on the elliptic curve $E$ given by $y^2 = x^3 + B \pmod n$, such that $B = - m_1^3 + m_2^2$.

For encrypt message $m$, add $P$ to itself $e$ times on E to obtain $C = e.P$

---

Source: Zhaohui Cheng's [*Simple Tutorial on Elliptic Curve Cryptography*](http://www.eis.mdx.ac.uk/staffpages/m_cheng/link/ecc_simple.pdf#page=19) (December 2004).

Comment: Is the curve-order public?

Comment: So I presume that ECRSA is just the scheme displayed here? I don't see any references about it on the internet...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes After a quick glance, it looks like the system described in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48285-7_4).

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: @fkraiem I think the question is: what are the feasible attacks on this cryptosystem (guessed from the title). Could be overly broad, asking for references, or requiring original research; I could well be answerable though. Lisbeth: can you confirm this is the question and that the system is described by the paper referenced by yyyyyyy?

Comment: @fkraiem How I can break this crypto system? Is there any known attacks?

Comment: @SEJPM You can see that crypto system [here](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~halatsis/Crypto/Bibliografia/Elliptic/ecc_simple.pdf)

Comment: My first impression is that the key size must be RSA like, e.g. 2048 bits. This renders the ECC advantage of having small key sizes worthless. So, despite security, what is the advantage of this crypto system?

Comment: Nit: $E$ is not an elliptic curve, as it is defined over a ring, not a field.

Comment: @poncho We can define elliptic curves on commutative rings, see [there](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95408/elliptic-curves-over-rings), and you can see why not on non-commutative rings [there](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7917/non-commutative-algebraic-geometry/15196#15196)

Comment: Using the standard addition law for finite-field elliptic curves, you get an operation that isn't closed; that is, there exist pairs of points where the addition law doesn't work (as the requisite modular inverse doesn't exist).  So, what addition law do you use?

Comment: Worse than possible failing inversions, which would reveal the factorization, is the fact that singular curves with $B = 0$ are allowed. In that case, decryption doesn't work due to the different order $pq$ than the $(p+1)(q+1)$ assumed.

Comment: ... and how can we decrypt this, how to calculate P from C?

Comment: I guess the decryption is as $P=d.C$, working under the assumption that the curve's order is $\lambda$, which in the reference now linked at the bottom of the question is justified by projecting on $\Bbb F_p$ and $\Bbb F_q$ giving curves of order $p+1$ and $q+1$. Among what I do not get is if $B$ is necessary for that decryption, in which case it must come along the ciphertext, which I have a feeling could open to attack. In other words, is it sound to work on a plaintext-dependent elliptic curve, as the proposed cryptosystem does? Or is this a snipe hunt? If so, it did work to a degree.